# Python select exists SQLite3 with variable

Tags: variables, python-3.x, sqlite, exists

I am to be unable to get the following code to work. I know how to use python variables in queries, but somehow I can't get this right. The query works fine when I hard code the 'icaocode' variable in the query, but not if I try to use a variable. What is wrong with this code?

```
icaocode = input()

c.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM airports WHERE ICAO = ?)", (icaocode))
if c.fetchone():
    print("Found!")
else:
    print("Not found...")
```

Received error:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 4 supplied.
```

Comment: What do you see if you `print icaocode`? How about `print type(icaocode)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, wrapping an expression in parentheses does not make any difference, `(icaocode)` is exactly the same as `icaocode`.

The `execute` method expects some kind of *list* of parameters, so it sees the string as a sequence of four characters.

To tell Python that you want a tuple with a single element, you have to add a comma:

```
c.execute("... WHERE ICAO = ?", (icaocode,))
```

Comment: This did the job! Thanks